# Android Emulator crashing with GLES 2.x config

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

My android emulator is crashing with this error.

```
C:\Users\Rakshit\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_23
Hax is enabled
init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!
Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
```

My emulator used to run fine till yesterday but ever since I updated my Windows 10 and Android Studio, it has stopped. I tried updating the graphics driver but that is fine as well.
I did turn off the gpu but then my emulator runs very sluggishly. I checked many posts here regarding this and have found similar solutions.
Could you please help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open AVD Manager
2. Edit this AVD (the button is at the 'actions' column)
3. Emulated Performance，Graphics：Software-GLE 2.0
4. finish the configuration and restart your virtual device again

   #### Select 'Software-GLE 2.0' for  Graphics，not select 'Automatic' or 'Hardware-GLE 2.0' (emulate graphics in software)