# Android Studio Error | Emulator: emulator: ERROR: VkCommonOperations.cpp:496: Failed to create Vulkan instance

Tags: android-studio

As the title shows I have an issue with Android Studio on my Linux Mint 19.3. I've tried to install Android Studio via the official download page, the Software Manager and now latest via snap. The failed to create vulkan instance is the first error of many when I try to launch an app in android studio 3.6.1. The emulator screen is black and nothing happens.

I run `Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic` on a `Dell XPS 13 9343` and the `Kernel: 5.3.0-40-generic x86_64`. I have all drivers installed.

This is the event log when I try to launch my app:

```
17.3.2020
10:32   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project /home/samuel/Downloads/Exemple2

10:32   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: VkCommonOperations.cpp:496: Failed to create Vulkan instance.

10:32   Emulator: emulator: WARNING: EmulatorService.cpp:448: Cannot find certfile: /home/samuel/.android/emulator-grpc.cer security will be disabled.

10:32   Emulator: E0317 10:32:43.165019034   12845 socket_utils_common_posix.cc:201] check for SO_REUSEPORT: {"created":"@1584433963.164985521","description":"SO_REUSEPORT unavailable on compiling system","file":"/mnt/tmpfs/src/android/emu-master-dev/external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.cc","file_line":169}

10:32   Emulator: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554

10:32   Gradle build finished in 1 s 288 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to lauch emulator after understanding it was a GPU issue...

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Made upgrade my Nvidia GPU drivers and changed problem to another :

> Blockquote
> Error while Running Android Application - Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it

So according to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686324/error-while-running-android-application-could-not-initialize-opengles-emulatio) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40406917/android-emulator-crashing-with-gles-2-x-config)
I changed the emulated device for one that allowed me to change  'Software-GLE 2.0' for Graphics，not select 'Automatic' or 'Hardware-GLE 2.0' (emulate graphics in software) (not all of them allow to change it)
I used Galaxy Nexus API 30 - R and emulation worked, even I still have this SO_REUSEPORT error !
Hope it can help someone ...

Answer (score 0):

Run this command on your terminal

```sh
sudo apt-get install mesa-vulkan-drivers
```

Comment: There was a downvote on this answer when I first get here, but this worked for me.