# Ubuntu android studio AVD error: Emulator: emulator: ERROR: VkCommonOperations.cpp:540: Failed to create Vulkan instance

Tags: android, android-studio, avd-manager

In android studio I created a device in AVD and when I click the play button I get this:

[image]

Here are the logs:

```
12:22 PM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: VkCommonOperations.cpp:540: Failed to create Vulkan instance.

12:22 PM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

This is a react native project that runs successfully when I connect a physical device, so I think the problem is with android studio itself and not the project.

What I've tried:

1. `$ sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers` according to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/573336/android-studio-error-emulator-emulator-error-vkcommonoperations-cpp496-fa)
2. `$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62798841/1226072)
3. Reinstalling android studio and creating a new device in the AVD

I have no idea how to solve this, so any help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: found any solution

Comment: no solution so far, please upvote the question so it will get more attention

Answer (score 0):

After spent a whole day I have found the solution. Just uninstall the existing system image of your emualtor and then download the new Google play system image emulator . It works for me!!

Comment: can you elaborate on "download the new Google play system image emulator"? do you mean add a device to AVD? please add more details :)

Comment: While creating new AVD it will show download option to select the R or Q or Pie.... in that window, just click on it and then complete the process. That's it