# Android Emulator gives an Error SO_REUSEPORT and debugging not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting following error when running emulator, also debugging is not working, it says waiting for debugger to attach. I am wondering if the following has anything to do with getting stuck at "waiting for debugger to attach".

> Emulator: E0516 21:01:34.057349753    3279
>   socket_utils_common_posix.cc:201] check for SO_REUSEPORT:
>   {"created":"@1589644894.057229268","description":"SO_REUSEPORT
>   unavailable on compiling
>   system","file":"/mnt/tmpfs/src/android/emu-master-dev/external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.cc","file_line":169}

My android studio version is below.

Android Studio 3.6.3
Build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6392135, built on April 14, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 5.4.0-29-generic
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1246M
Cores: 4
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins:

Comment: same problem, found a solution?

Comment: No solution to resolve this error, but my debugging is now magically working on the same emulator

Comment: Having you given any thought about what changed? I just ran into the same problem after updating the 3.6.3 running on Ubuntu 18.4 Full error: 3:11 PM Emulator: E0524 15:11:34.211875852   15071 socket_utils_common_posix.cc:201] check for SO_REUSEPORT: {"created":"@1590347494.211844937","description":"SO_REUSEPORT unavailable on compiling system","file":"/mnt/tmpfs/src/android/emu-master-dev/external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.cc","file_line":169}

Comment: 3.6.3 was working fine, I just updated the emulator version and then this started to happen

Answer (score 2):

I had that problem.

I was making a wrong diagnostic.

Running the emulator from  `Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator` with a command such as:

`./emulator @Pixel_3_API_28 -netdelay none -netspeed full -debug all` also gave me this error, but it is non-blocking.

The problem disappeared when I:

- switched to proprietary driver (nvidia) in Ubuntu in the Software Updater > Settings > Additional Driver
- Restarting
- Recreating my virtual device.

Comment: Which version are you using? I'm having the same problem and they are 2 propietary nvidia-driver-435 and nvidia-driver-440.

Comment: I'm using the `nvidia-driver-440 (proprietary, tested)`.
(I have a GeForce GTX 780 if this is relevant)

Answer (score 2):

For me the device was working fine until this error started coming up.

Android Studio -> Open AVD Manager -> Select Virtual Device ->  Wipe Data fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is maybe related to fix in Emulator 30.0.18 (https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/06/emulator-30018-canary.html). Try to update your emulator with different channel

```
sdkmanager --channel=3 "emulator"
```

For "waiting for debugger to attach" try to also delete all breakpoints if it helps.

ps: I am a bit duplicating my answer with https://stackoverflow.com/a/62793395/13891284 but can't really mark as duplicate

Comment: Could you say how to do it in Android Studio?

Comment: Follow [Update the IDE and SDK Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update) but I don't think you can do it just for specific tool via IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to lauch emulator after understanding it was a GPU issue...

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Changed problem to another :

> Blockquote
> Error while Running Android Application - Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it

So according to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686324/error-while-running-android-application-could-not-initialize-opengles-emulatio) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40406917/android-emulator-crashing-with-gles-2-x-config)
I changed the emulated device for one that allowed me to change  'Software-GLE 2.0' for Graphics，not select 'Automatic' or 'Hardware-GLE 2.0' (emulate graphics in software) (not all of them allow to change it)
I used Galaxy Nexus API 30 - R and emulation worked, even I still have this SO_REUSEPORT error !
Hope it can help someone ...

Answer (score 0):

The emulator was showing a android setup notification. Once I clicked on that and setup the phone, the emulator started working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Switching the camera options from `Emulated` to `None` fixed it [for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63038064/4420543).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Linux, Since I have two graphics card in my laptop, by default I was in powersave mode(Intel). Switching it to Performance mode(Nvidia) solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to the Graphics settings - specifically if you choose Hardware GPU; Either disable the GPU or choose software emulation;
Change it from the UI of the emulator, or directly in the config.ini file (in Linux at `~/.android/avd-emulator-name/config.ini`):

```
hw.gpu.enabled=yes
hw.gpu.mode=software
```