# Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, vulkan

This is error constantly troubling me.

```
2:48 PM Emulator: E0703 14:48:54.862877684    8457 socket_utils_common_posix.cc:201] check for SO_REUSEPORT: {"created":"@1593767934.862700600","description":"SO_REUSEPORT unavailable on compiling system","file":"/mnt/tmpfs/src/android/emu-master-dev/external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.cc","file_line":169}
```

The description given is :

```
"description":"SO_REUSEPORT unavailable on compiling system","file":"/mnt/tmpfs/src/android/emu-master-dev/external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.cc","file_line":169
```

Comment: I have the same issue under Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is maybe related to fix in Emulator 30.0.18 (https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/06/emulator-30018-canary.html). Try to update your emulator with different channel

```
sdkmanager --channel=3 "emulator"
```

Comment: How to use this command? Can you help more on this? It will be very helpful. I tried on terminal but it is showing:
```sdkmanager: command not found```
And yes thank you for answering.

Comment: It should come with AndroidStudio. If you don't have it follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/62119971/13891284 to install [Command line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#command-tools).

Comment: I installed Canary version, the issue got resolved. Thank You very much.